# subsetting columns of a matrix by using column names

Tags: matrix, subset, stata

I'm sorry if this is a basic question, but I couldn't find any solution, neither here nor on the Stata manual (chapter 14, "Matrix expressions").

My goal is to subset a matrix by using column names.
My initial matrix `A` looks like this:

```
mat A = (1,2,3\4,5,6\7,8,9)
mat rownames A = "row a" "row b" "row c"
mat colnames A = "col x" "col y" "col z"

mat list A
```

I need to create a matrix that is composed by the first and the last columns using the column names `col x` and `col z`.
The "closest" thing I was able to perform is:

```
mat B = A[.,"col x".."col z"]
```

which is clearly wrong. Any other attempt resulted in a matrix `B` composed by the first column only.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is:

```
mat A = (1,2,3\4,5,6\7,8,9)
mat rownames A = "row a" "row b" "row c"
mat colnames A = "col x" "col y" "col z"
matrix list A

matrix B = A[1...,colnumb(A,"col x")], A[1...,colnumb(A,"col z")]
matrix list B
```

This extracts all rows of both `"col x"` and `"col z"`, and uses the column-join operator `,` (comma) to put them together.

Another is:

```
matrix C = A["row a".."row c" , "col x"], A["row a".."row c" , "col z"]
```

And yet another:

```
matrix D = A[1... , "col x"], A[1... , "col z"]
```

See also Stata's matrix programming language, **Mata** (`help mata`). It's more complex, but much more powerful.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I already started looking into Mata, I think it's definitely worth investing time on this. Thanks a lot for the support!